# How to prevent repeating combinations of two random numbers?

Tags: php, random

Here my my code for generating the three-word combinations (combo_generator.php):

```
<?php

include "db_connect.php";

// Query database of words
$words_sql    = "SELECT * FROM words";
$words_res    = mysqli_query($db, $words_sql)or die(mysqli_error());

// Create array of words
$array  = array();

// Loop through each word and add each to the array
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($words_res)){
     $array[] = $row['word'];
}

// Set $word1 as random word from $array
$ran_num = array_rand($array);
$word1   = $array[$ran_num];

// Remove the chosen word from the array
array_splice($array, $ran_num, 1);

// Reset the array
$array2 = $array;

// Set $word2 as random word from $array
$ran_num2 = array_rand($array2);
$word2    = $array2[$ran_num2];

// Set variables 
$word        = 'star';
$three_words = "$word.$word1.$word2";

echo $three_words;

?>
```

Here is my code for assigning a random three-word combination to each star from the database (test.php):

```
<?php

include "db_connect.php";

// Pull all stars from database
$stars_sql = "SELECT * FROM stars";
$stars_res = mysqli_query($db, $stars_sql)or die(mysqli_error());

// Loop through every star in the array
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($stars_res)){
     // Store the star name in a variable
     $star = $row['star_name'];

     // Create a random 3-word combination
     include "combo_generator.php"; 

     // Attach the random 3-word combination to the star 
     echo $star.'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$three_words.'<br/><br/>';
}

?>
```

I'm trying to generate three-word combinations in the form star.word1.word2, where word1 is a random word from the database, and word2 is a different random word from the database (word1 != word2). Each combination that is generated is then assigned to a star from the database.

How do I avoid repeating combinations? By repeating combinations I mean the following:

Combination 1: star.lamp.chair; Combination 2: star.dog.ball; Combination 3: star.ball.dog; Combination 4: star.lamp.chair

Here, combination 1 and combination 4 are the same - this repetition is what I want to avoid. The order is not important, so combination 2 and combination 3 are fine.

Comment: Could you provide the code you use the repeat the process? There must be some loop or request happening to get more than one take?

Comment: or `shuffle` array and `array_slice`

Comment: I'm assuming that you're calling this script from some kind of application multiple times to get multiple combinations? If so, you could save all your already generated combinatons and check if the new combination is the same as any of them. If it is, create a new combination.

Comment: I've edited my post to reflect the creation of multiple combinations - apologies.

Comment: if you are saving those 3words in your database or server you can use a recursive function  to check if combo generator used the name it generates before and if it did repeat all over tell there are no repeat
you can also use time().$word1.$word2 Time() is unique and won't be repeated ever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an array with all possible word pairs, and then do the pick-and-remove from that array:

```
<?php

// Retrieve a list of words from the DB and build the pairs list
include "db_connect.php";

// Query database of words
$words_sql = "SELECT * FROM words";
$words_res = mysqli_query($db, $words_sql)or die(mysqli_error());

// Create array of words
$array  = array();

// Loop through each word and add each to the array
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($words_res)){
    $array[] = $row['word'];
}

// Create all valid pairs
$pairs = array();
foreach ($array as $word1) {
    foreach ($array as $word2) {
        if ($word1 !== $word2) {
            $pairs[] = "$word1.$word2";
        }
    }
}

// Pull all stars from database
$stars_sql = "SELECT * FROM stars";
$stars_res = mysqli_query($db, $stars_sql)or die(mysqli_error());

// Loop through every star in the array
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($stars_res)){
    // Store the star name in a variable
    $star = $row['star_name'];

    // Set $pair as random word from $pairs
    $ran_num = array_rand($pairs);
    $pair = $pairs[$ran_num];

    // ... and remove it
    array_splice($pairs, $ran_num, 1);

    // Set variables 
    $word        = 'star';
    $three_words = "$word.$pair";

    // Attach the random 3-word combination to the star 
    echo $star.'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$three_words.'<br/><br/>';
}

?>
```

Comment: This can be very slow if there is a lot of words. And if the number of needed combinations is little, it is unnecessary. Check my answer.

Comment: Both answers are viable and have their pros and cons.

Comment: Of course, I just wanted to note that. If there is a lot of words and a lot of needed combinations, your answer is way better.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers. Since I intend to use a large database of words, the array will contain an extremely large number of possible combinations. I've hence implemented the solution by @trincot.

Answer (score 2):

You could save which combinations were already created.

Create a global array (=a variable in test.php) that represents all already created combinations:

```
/*@var $createdCombinations array*/
$createdCombinations=[];
```

Then, before just echoing your new combination, check if it has been already created. If not, add it to the array. If yes, create a new combination.

Like so:

```
// ...

while(true){
    // Set $word1 as random word from $array
    $ran_num = array_rand($array);
    $word1   = $array[$ran_num];

    // ...

    if(!in_array($three_words,$createdCombinations)){
        $createdCombinations[]=$three_words;
        echo $three_words;
        break;
    }
}
```

Other parts of the code can stay the same, so they were omitted.

Comment: You're welcome. Note that If you have a very large number of words and a few needed combinations, this answer is actually better than the accepted one. The accepted answer will take a lot of time at the beginning. But this one will take a little time for each combination. SO if you will only be taking small amount of combinations, this answer is faster than the accepted one. But if you will be taking a lot of combinations (1000+), then the accepted answer is faster.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. My intention is to use a large database of words, where no. of combinations > no. of words. For that reason I accepted trincot's answer, as you graciously advised :-) .